What's the differences between ap2a and trunk_staging in compiling AOSP?
I'm trying to compile AOSP source code. I don't understand the differences between trunk_staging and ap2a.
Most tutorials use the aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug to configure the compilation. But it seems the newest AOSP source code does not support this configuration and it will throw an error:
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:380:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:51:
build/make/core/release_config.mk:145: error: No release config found for TARGET_RELEASE: trunk_staging. Available releases are: ap2a.
15:01:23 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

If I use the aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-ap2a-userdebug, the compilation is success. Anyone familiar with AOSP can explain this?
